# Polymorphism issue

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have been reading on how to program Java 8 Polymorphism.

I have this code:

```
public class Person
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private int age;
    private boolean married;
    private float salary;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Person
     */
    public Person(String lastname, String firstname, int age, boolean married, float salary)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.lastname = new String(lastname);
        this.firstname = new String(firstname);
        this.age = age;
        this.married = married;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getLastName() {return lastname;}
    public String getFirstName() {return firstname;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public boolean isMarried() {return married;}
    public float getSalary() {return salary;}
}


public class MarriedPerson extends Person
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int children;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MarriedPerson
     */
    public MarriedPerson(String lastname, String firstname, int age, float salary, int children)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        super(lastname, firstname, age, true, salary);
        this.children = children;
    }

    public int getNoOfChildren()
    {
        // put your code here
        return children;
    }
}


abstract class MyTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Person p1 = new Person("Kings", "Paul", 22, true, 1200f);
       MarriedPerson mp1 = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Betty", 31, 980.5f, 3);
       System.out.print(p1.getFirstName()+" "+p1.getLastName()+" is "
       +p1.getAge()+" years old, gets a "+p1.getSalary()
       +" Euros salary and is");
       if (p1.isMarried() == false)
          System.out.print(" not");
       System.out.println(" married.");
       System.out.print(mp1.getFirstName()+" "+mp1.getLastName()
       +" is " +mp1.getAge()+ " years old, gets a " + mp1.getSalary()
       +" Euros salary and is" + " married with ");
       if (mp1.getNoOfChildren() > 0)
          System.out.print(mp1.getNoOfChildren());
       else System.out.print("no");
          System.out.println(" children.");
    }
}
```

Reading from a book, I have not seen an abstract class that contains the main function so I am a bit confused.

Why have we declared MyTester class as abstract? Is this necessary?

I have now created a printInfo method in class Person. See following code:

```
public class Person
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private int age;
    private boolean married;
    private float salary;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Person
     */
    public Person(String lastname, String firstname, int age, boolean married, float salary)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.lastname = new String(lastname);
        this.firstname = new String(firstname);
        this.age = age;
        this.married = married;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getLastName() {return lastname;}
    public String getFirstName() {return firstname;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public boolean isMarried() {return married;}
    public float getSalary() {return salary;}

    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.print(p1.getFirstName()+" "+p1.getLastName()+" is "
       +p1.getAge()+" years old, gets a "+p1.getSalary()
       +" Euros salary and is");
       if (p1.isMarried() == false)
          System.out.print(" not");
       System.out.println(" married."); 
    }
}

abstract class MyTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Person p1 = new Person("Kings", "Paul", 22, true, 1200f);
       MarriedPerson mp1 = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Betty", 31, 980.5f, 3);
       p1.printInfo();
       mp1.printInfo();    
    }
}
```

When I compile the modified code it give me the error: cannot find symbol - variable p1. Why is that? What do I need to do in order to fix that?
What advantages second code has over first one?

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. It makes no difference, as the class is never extended or used except as an entrypoint.

Comment: @Downvoter, please comment? I know the answer isn't in depth, but simplicity is required here as the question asks a simple question. It has since been edited to include more questions, but I answered before they were asked.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense MyTester to be abstract since it does not have any abstract method. The only reason might be to prevent the instantiation of MyTester class because it might not make sense for an instance to exist.

Answer (score 0):

MyTester is declared abstract so you can't create any instances of it (there is no reason you would want to). See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), it says:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed.

Comment: Does your answer refer to second question that gives an error regarding variable p1?

Comment: No, but for that issue, replace `p1` with `this`

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile the modified code it give me the error: cannot find symbol - variable p1. Why is that? What do I need to do in order to fix that?

For future reference: You should create a new question and not edit your existing one. Also, if someone solved your first problem you should allways be so nice as to accept their answer. ;)

Anyway: You are getting that error because your object is only "known" as p1 in your main class. 
In your "printInfo()" method you are trying to have the objects do calls on itself. So either just remove the "p1." part and just call the methods like "getFirstName()", or explicitly call "this.getFirstName()".

("this" is a java keyword refering to the current object instance.)

A tipp for you: Get a good JAVA IDE like Eclipse (https://eclipse.org/) and you will see simple errors like those even before compiling.

Comment: thanks 911DidBush. I thought that a new question to a related issue would not be answered. I am using BlueJ but I will be using NetBeans in future aswell